# SSAS attribute key cannot be found

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'table1', Column: 'STRT_DT', Value: '6/1/2007 10:16:57'. The attribute is 'Date'.

I got this error after linking the fact "table1" with time dimension table
and after investigation i found that the STRT_DT value is not found because, the value in the Date dimension is like 6/1/2007 00:00:00

so is there any way to link the dates only without the timestamp ??

Answer (score 0):

using the convert function `(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110))` convert the data and link it .

Comment: thanks Adi for your help but is there any property i can change inside the tool itself ??

Comment: Not as far as I know.  Better to cleanse the data in the source tables as part of ETL so that fact rows definitely have a date key that matches something in the date dimension.